# Direct sum of vector subsoaces of $\mathbb{Q}[x]_{\leq 5}$

Tags: linear-algebra

So basically I am working with the space $V=\mathbb{Q}[x]_{\leq 5}$, I am given the subspace $W=\{ p(x)\in\mathbb{Q}[x]_{\leq 5} : p(x)=p(-x)\}$, I have shown that this is a three dimensional subspace and in particular $W=Span\{1,x^2,x^4\}$. Now i have to find two distinct subspaces $T_1$ and $T_2$ such that $V=W\oplus T_1=W\oplus T_2$. One is pretty obvious, $T_1=Span\{x,x^3,x^5\}$, but I can't think of another one, I know this isn't very hard but I'm having an hard time figuring it out so please help :)))

Comment: Hint: Consider including something like $x+1$ in $T_2$.